Is there a way to use Intel QSV to have hwaccelerated tone mapping in ffmpeg?
Currently I am trying ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i "Z://Movies/Luca/Luca.mkv" -vf 'hwdownload,format=p010,zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=hable,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=yuv420p' -c:v h264_qsv -crf 21 -c:a aac Z://Luca.mkv, but I wanted to know if I could use hardware acceleration for the tonemapping. Thanks

There is a very limited support with vpp_qsv filter.  Output of ffmpeg -h filter=vpp_qsv has the following description: tonemap  ... Perform tonemapping (0=disable tonemapping, 1=perform tonemapping if the input has HDR metadata) (from 0 to 1) (default 0). Please note that I don't know what is the referred "HDR metadata".

I was able to get it running with this command ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i "Z://Movies/Luca/Luca.mkv" -vf "vpp_qsv=tonemap=1,scale_qsv=format=nv12" -c:v h264_qsv -crf 23 -c:a aac "Z://Luca.mkv" but it didn't seem to change the color space.
